# How to change a shape project when obstructed by object

Tags: projection, mesh

I have a customized shape (mesh) in 3D as shown below:
[image: Customized shape - mesh]

Now that customized shape projection will change when there are several obstacles located in front of the customized shape.
I expect the result to look like this:
[image: Customized shape after obstructed]

Questions:
1) How do I change the customized shape project when there are obstacles located in front? Which mathematical formula or theory can I use?

Please advise.
Thank you.